# Are the error_perm and msg in "except error_perm, msg" special?

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm reading this [script](http://code.google.com/p/ftpsync2d/source/browse/trunk/ftpsync.py).  It synchronizes files via FTP.

I'm confused with this statement in line 106

```
try:
    ...
except error_perm, msg:
    ...
```

It seems the variables **error_perm** and **msg** come from nowhere.  When the **try** part goes wrong, the script halts and fails to go into the **except** part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the next import on the top of the file:

```
from ftplib import FTP, error_perm
```

`error_perm` is an error class.

statement

```
except error_perm, msg:
```

catches any exception with type `error_perm` and stores exception object in variable `msg`.

Comment: Thanks!  Does it mean "error_perm, msg" are supposed to be evaluated as True when there is an error in the **try** part?

Comment: @zjk it is not evaluated neither as `True` nor as `False`.  If Python's exception handling is unfamiliar to you, I would suggest reading the doc - http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

import is correct, exception handling is a bit different syntax for python 3.6 and up:

```
except error_perm as msg:
    print(f"FTP error: {msg}",flush=True)
```